# Unable to return POST data from multipart form using Multer / Express

Tags: node.js, express, git-bash, multer

Using multer with expressjs I can't seem to get a console.log() response in my Git Bash shell when posting data from a multipart form.  Note, I'm only returning text so I do have the "upload.none()" applied in the post request.

Not sure if I have a problem within my register.jade file or in the users.js file itself...

Does multer require an "app.use(....) statement in app.js?  I didn't see anything in the documentation

My Form (register.jade):

```html
body.animsition
    .page-wrapper
      .page-content--bge5
        .container
          .login-wrap
            .login-content
              .login-logo
                a(href='#')
                  img(src='/images/QTI-Logo.jpg', alt='')
              .login-form
                form(action='/users/register', method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data')
                .form-group
                    label Full Name
                    input.au-input.au-input--full(type='text', name='name', placeholder='Your Name')
                  .form-group
                    label Username
                    input.au-input.au-input--full(type='text', name='username', placeholder='Desired Username')
                  .form-group
                    label Email Address
                    input.au-input.au-input--full(type='email', name='email', placeholder='Email')
                  .form-group
                    label Password
                    input.au-input.au-input--full(type='password', name='password', placeholder='Password')
                  .form-group
                    label Confirm Password
                    input.au-input.au-input--full(type='password', name='password2', placeholder='Confirm Password')
                  input.au-btn.au-btn--block.au-btn--green.m-b-20(type='submit', name='submit' value='Register')
                .register-link
                  p
                    | Already have account?
                    br
                    a(href='/users/login') Sign In
```

Here's the users.js file:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', {title: 'Register'});
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {title: 'Login'});
});

router.post('/register', upload.none(), function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.name);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this issue as well, I finally found my error!!

Damn Jade/Pug formatting.  That's what I get for trusting an online HTML >> Jade convertor I guess.

```
.login-form
            form(action='/users/register', method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data')
              .form-group
                  label Full Name
                  input.au-input.au-input--full(type='text', name='name', placeholder='Your Name')
                .form-group
                  label Username
                  input.au-input.au-input--full(type='text', name='username', placeholder='Desired Username')
                .form-group
                  label Email Address
                  input.au-input.au-input--full(type='email', name='email', placeholder='Email')
                .form-group
                  label Password
                  input.au-input.au-input--full(type='password', name='password', placeholder='Password')
                .form-group
                  label Confirm Password
                  input.au-input.au-input--full(type='password', name='password2', placeholder='Confirm Password')
                input.au-btn.au-btn--block.au-btn--green.m-b-20(type='submit', name='submit' value='Register')
            .register-link
              p
                | Already have account?
                br
                a(href='/users/login') Sign In
```

The .form-group needed one extra "tab" or indent for this all to work.  And here I was chasing down express and multer errors for 3 days